# Need help R - Naive Bayes

Tags: r, machine-learning, dataset, classification, bayesian

Here is the last view of my data from R and its resulting error

[image: data view and showing error]

This data is in 0, 1, 2 format of a phenotype data.  The last column holds the label value having first 1000 values being zero and the next 1000 values being 1.  Please do ask me if there is more information needed.  The variable 'data' holds the file that is shown below in the view.  I have e1071 package installed and running Naïve Bayes to do prediction.  I apologize if my explanation relating to my project misleads in any way and if the formatting of this post is incorrect. Please help with the error that I am getting.
Thank you.

Comment: The formatting is "incorrect" in the sense that if you had posted any code and expected us to extract data from the posted console "picture" it would have been impossible. Learn to post text output and do not use screenshots for anything except graphics.

Comment: Compare `predict(classifier, data)` and `data[, 11]`. Are they vectors of equal length?

Answer (score 0):

I know this would sound obvious, but, i think data or classifier, one of those two, is bigger than the other, you should check. Because the image (screenshot), shows that you are showing a matrix that has 11 columns (i suppose is the one you call data), so, you should check classifier if it has the same dimentions.

Comment: I have checked the data file.  The file does have 11 columns.